# Python: getting the first 100 most recent keys in amazon s3 bucket

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I tried using boto, but it has the `.list()` method, which takes way to long for my data set, and the `.get_all_keys()`, which gets it random. I want to get about 100-1000 of the most recent keys in my S3 bucket, which has millions of keys in it. What is the most efficient way of doing this.

Comment: sort based on LastModified.

Comment: @kartheek the thing is I cannot load all of my keys before sorting based in last_modified – it takes way too long to even load all the keys. Maybe you can show me some code of what you mean exactly – maybe I'm understanding you wrong.

Comment: You cannot do this efficiently using S3 APIs if there are millions of keys. You're going to have to either use an S3 inventory from the previous day, or maintain your own database of keys, sorted in whatever fashion you want.

Comment: @jarmood ok, I see. Is there a way that I can load more. Like using a fetch_more function or something like that?

Comment: @jarmood even getting 1000 (random) keys that has been last_modified in August would do.

Comment: There's no better solution than the two options that I previously proposed, to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3')

start_after = “”

response =  client.list_objects(Bucket='<bucket>', StartAfter =start_after,MaxKeys=1000)
```

you save response['Contents'] which has LastModified key.

```
'Contents': [
    {
        'Key': 'string',
        'LastModified': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
        'ETag': 'string',
        'Size': 123,
        'StorageClass': 'STANDARD'|'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY'|'GLACIER'|'STANDARD_IA'|'ONEZONE_IA',
        'Owner': {
            'DisplayName': 'string',
            'ID': 'string'
        }
    },
],
```

get the last key from this 1000 records and assign this to the **start_after** variable and make another requests this time.

The new request start fetching keys that are after the key startAfter provides.

https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. But generating `objs` is the part that I have some issues in.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the data being slightly out of date, you could use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily CSV file listing all of your objects in the Amazon S3 bucket:

> Amazon S3 inventory provides comma-separated values (CSV) or Apache optimized row columnar (ORC) output files that list your objects and their corresponding metadata on a daily or weekly basis for an S3 bucket or a shared prefix (that is, objects that have names that begin with a common string).

You could parse this file to obtain Keys and Last Modified dates, then sort by date.